# How can we deploy multiple mico service in a single server

Tags: spring-boot, web-deployment, spring-cloud, continuous-deployment

I have bellow microservice

1. register server
2. zuul server
3. config server
4. Emp-service
5. department-service

Those are in different ports how can we deploy those in server?

Comment: Maybe explain more where you are blocked. In general multiple services can be deployed on a server, but there are plenty of methods for how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the there is no simple answer to this. I guess you are trying to learn microservices, your services are working fine on local machine and now would like to know learn how should you deploy it in some standalone server. Your deployment strategy depends on lot if variable factors. When you say "deploy those in server" I assume you want to deploy them on a remote linux server.

For starters, you can just create jars of your applications, move jar to your remote machine and run them (read `java -jar` command). Or, you can containerize. You are already using spring cloud, you may want to use docker to containerize your applications and then deploy it on a server, the basic steps to do that should go like this:

1. Create DockerFile in your applications (Search for, Spring boot
   Docker File for samples, you can also look at this [hello world project](https://github.com/sumeetmondal/spring-boot-rest-hello.git)). This is the file where you mention details about your jar, port on which you want it to expose/map internally-externally etc.
2. Create Docker images from your applications
   (read about docker build command)
3. Push the Docker images to some remote image repository (you can use
   Dockerhub)
4. Pull and run that image into your remote server (read about docker
   pull, docker run commands)

Again, there is no straight answer to this. You need to read more about containerization, various container-orchestration platforms etc. I suggest, you start from learn the basics of microservices and why we need them and then move to code and deployment

PS: Looking at your current set of services, I think you will also need a service registry like eureka

Comment: I am using JBoss server for deploying those services.

Comment: May I know what factor lead to JBoss? It will just create a complex infrastructure for micro services considering you run single JBoss for each for each MS. If you deploy all in one JBoss server, then I don't see any point. Yes, feasible, but whats the point!